# Combining Excel Sheets into the summary sheet for specific sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run this code but only for specific worksheet names. the name is as follows `"X_Score_" & CurrentDate` where `CurrentDate` changes every time the loop runs.  Right now it runs for all worksheets in the whole workbook which is quite messy.

```
Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX_SCORE_TOTAL")
  
               RowTracker = 2
               flag = False
                
               For Each bs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    
                    If UCase(bs.Name) <> "XXX_SCORE_TOTAL" Then
                        LastRow = bs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                        LastColumn = bs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        
                    End If
                    
                    bs.Range(bs.Cells(2, 1), bs.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy wsMaster.Cells(RowTracker, 1)
                    
                    RowTracker = RowTracker + LastRow
                    
               Next bs
```

I tried to predifine something like `Set MyCollection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X_Score_" & CurrentDate)` and then put in in the For loop like `For Each bs In MyCollection`but it didn't worked

Comment: _Right now it runs for the whole worksheet which is quite messy._ You probaly mean _Right now it runs for **all worksheets in** the whole work**book** which is quite messy._ Right?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to process all sheets in the workbook whose names start with "X_Score_", this can be done with `Left()`:

```
Sub test1()
    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX_SCORE_TOTAL")
  
    RowTracker = 2
    flag = False
     
    For Each bs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' or ActiveWorkbook?
        If Left(UCase(bs.Name), 8) = "X_SCORE_" Then
            
            LastRow = bs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            LastColumn = bs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            Set Rng = bs.Range(bs.Cells(2, 1), bs.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
            Rng.Copy wsMaster.Cells(RowTracker, 1)
            
            RowTracker = RowTracker + Rng.Rows.Count ' shift RowTracker according to the number of rows copied 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I run this code and the final sheet is empty

Comment: The only problem now is that it keeps overwriting the data

Comment: do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: I can't use remove duplicates because it deletes too much

Comment: @BobMac while I have not seen your data, it is difficult to offer a solution

Comment: @BobMac I think that if the problem with data duplication is not directly related to the original question, it is advisable to create a new question and describe the situation qualitatively

Comment: Hi, I managed to find the solution :)

Comment: @BobMac Great, congratulations :)

Comment: It turns out to be a partial solution: so the file name looks like that XXXX_SCORE_YYYYMMDD and the difference is on DD first digit so `Left(UCase(bs.Name), 17) right ?`

Comment: yes, i think so